# 'NoReverseMatch' Error When Trying to Pass JSONResponse to D3 (Django)

Tags: django, d3.js, django-templates, django-views

I have an app called 'funds' that has two models: fund, and performance. Performance tracks the fund. What I was trying to do is graph the performance using D3.js. However I came across this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /funds/morning-glory-volatility-fund/
>
> Reverse for 'performance_api' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['funds/(?P[\w-]+)/performance/api']

Here is my view that I am using to pass the JSONResponse:

```
def performance_api(request, fund_slug):
    fund = get_object_or_404(Fund, slug=fund_slug)

    data = Performance.objects.filter(fund__name=fund.name) \
        .extra(select={'month': connections[Performance.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date')}) \
        .values('month') \
        .annotate(count_items=Count('id'))
    return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
```

and the urls.py for my funds app:

```
url(r'^(?P<fund_slug>[\w-]+)/performance/api', views.performance_api, name='performance_api'),
```

there is also another global urls.py that includes the url from all of my apps. But to access the performance_api in broswer it would look something like this: '127.168.1.1/funds/fund_slug/perfomance/api' which seems to be working.

As for the D3 code it is about 40 lines so I will only post the portion that seems to be causing the issue:

```
d3.json("{% url 'performance_api' %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.month = parseDate(d.month);
    d.count_items = +d.count_items;
  });
```

Any idea on what's causing this issue and how I can solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url pattern for `performance_api` features one named argument (`fund_slug`). In order for the `url` tag to reverse this url, you need to provide this information, e.g.

```
d3.json("{% url 'performance_api' fund_slug="morning-glory-volatility-fund" %}", function(error, data) { //... }
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to give `fund_slug` in the `url` tag:

```
{% url 'performance_api' here_fund_slug %}
```